# yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping in "./docker-compose.yml"

Tags: docker-compose

### Error:yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping in "./docker-compose.yml", line 6, column 5 expected , but found '' in "./docker-compose.yml", line 15, column 6

```yml
version: '3'

services:
  # Database
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
            - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
     networks:
        - wpsite
  # Wordpress
  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    restart: always
    volumes: ['./:/var/www/html']
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - wpsite
networks:
  wpsite:
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the indentation.
The `networks` section of `db` is one space ahead of `environment`.

You can use as many spaces as you like, as long as all the (sub-)sections at the same level of nesting use the same amount of indentation.